# Menu does not close

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I am creating a menu that supposed to be web accessible with 508 compliance. The problem is when I get to the last menu item the menu does not close while the keyboard TAB button.

Another problem is I need to be able find a way to close the menu when clicking on the ESC key

The sample is here: jsfiddle.net/dvLden/Ltz7nmdb/1/

Comment: Just use selecter:not( :hover ){ ... } in your css

Comment: I need to do it on focus. because I will be only using the keyboard

Comment: you can Combining all together same as selecter:not(:hover, :focus, .active) { ... }

Comment: can You make a change here so I visually see it.  [link]www. jsfiddle.net/dvLden/Ltz7nmdb/1/

Comment: jsfiddle.net/dvLden/Ltz7nmdb/1/

Comment: [Here you have all accessible ways](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/flyout/) on how to create such a flyout menu.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to change:

```
/* CSS */

.navbar > .navbar-item:hover > .navbar-sub,
.navbar > .navbar-item a:focus ~ .navbar-sub {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is the full working code (without jQuery):

```css
/* CSS */

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
.navbar,
.navbar .navbar-sub {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar > .navbar-item {
    float: left;
}
.navbar > .navbar-item:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.navbar > .navbar-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar > .navbar-item > a {
    background-color: #999;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #696969;
    display: block;
}
.navbar > .navbar-item > a:hover,
.navbar > .navbar-item > a:focus,
.navbar > .navbar-item.active > a {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.navbar .navbar-sub {
    display: none;
}
.navbar .navbar-sub > .navbar-sub-item > a {
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #696969;
}
.navbar .navbar-item.active .navbar-sub-item > a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-item.active .navbar-sub-item > a:focus {
    background-color: #999;
}


/* That keep it open when "hover" and "focus" */
.navbar > .navbar-item:hover > .navbar-sub,
.navbar > .navbar-item a:focus ~ .navbar-sub {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<ul class="navbar">
    <li class="navbar-item">
        <a href="javascript:;">Parent Link</a>
        <ul class="navbar-sub">
            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">One</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">Two</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">Three</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-item">
        <a href="javascript:;">Parent Link</a>
        <ul class="navbar-sub">
            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">One</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">Two</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">Three</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-item">
        <a href="javascript:;">Parent Link</a>
        <ul class="navbar-sub">
            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">One</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">Two</a>
            </li>   
            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">Three</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-item">
        <a href="javascript:;">Parent Link</a>
        <ul class="navbar-sub">
            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">One</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">Two</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar-sub-item">
                <a href="#url_redirect">Three</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It  looks good now. However I can no longer tab through the menu Items only the top level

Comment: any suggestions